# String input with Scanner

Tags: java, string, input, output

I am trying to construct a simple 5 word sentence where each word labled and displayed. I.e. Subject-Verb, etc. Then at the end it would do an entire cohesive sentence. Yet When I run the code I get an error and I am not sure why.

```
public class Sentence {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO code application logic here
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Enter Subject:");
       int Subject = input.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Enter Verb:");
       int Verb = input.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Enter Adjective:");
       String Adjective;
       Adjective = input.next();

       System.out.println("Enter Object:");
       String Object;
       Object = input.next();

       System.out.println("Enter Adverb:");
       String Adverb;
       Adverb = input.next();

       System.out.println("Subject  + Verb + Adjective + Object + Adverb");

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please edit your question and add details about that error. We are no wizards here - and we have no clue what input you used - in case we are talking about runtime problems.

Comment: Please post the error that you are getting , it will help us to get quick answer for your problem.

Comment: This is probably a runtime problem. I think the issue is that your code is expecting an integer for the subject and verb. You probably want those to be accepting strings.

Answer (score 0):

i think that all must read string content (the two first wait for a int) so maybe u want some like this

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Subject:");
        String subject = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter Verb:");
        String verb = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter Adjective:");
        String adjective;
        adjective = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter Object:");
        String object;
        object = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter Adverb:");
        String adverb;
        adverb = input.next();

        System.out.println(subject + " " + verb + " " + adjective + " " + object + " " + adverb);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to make a cohensive sentence. Now,take a look at your code.You will see that you used integer that makes no sense.

1) You use Scanner but You didn't import Scanner class.That was your first problem. If you want to use Scanner, you should always import "Scanner class" at the start of your code.

2)You wanted to make a cohensive sentence so it should have words in it.But you used integer.You should'a use String and NextLine(); for it.

3)At the end of your code,`System.out.println("Subject  + Verb + Adjective + Object + Adverb");`
 Delete all the quotation marks and your code should work well.

So your code should look like this.